# how to find hive metastore is using derby or MYSQL as database?

Tags: hive, metastore

I am trying to find the hive remote meta-store is using `Derby` or `MYSQL` as database?

Is there a way to find this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check your `hive-site.xml`.

If there are following lines:

```
<property>
  <name>javax.jdo.option.ConnectionURL</name>
  <value>jdbc:mysql://<host name>/<database name>..</value>
<description>JDBC connect string for a JDBC metastore</description>
</property>
```

Your `meta-store` in `mysql`.

```
<property>
  <name>javax.jdo.option.ConnectionURL</name> 
  <value>jdbc:derby:;databaseName=../build/test/junit_metastore_db;create=true</value>
<description>JDBC connect string for a JDBC metastore</description>
</property>
```

Your `meta-store` in `derby`.

[More about configure meta-store](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/AdminManual+MetastoreAdmin#AdminManualMetastoreAdmin-Local/EmbeddedMetastoreDatabase(Derby))

---

**EDIT**

If the above line not in `hive-site.xml`, try searching in `hive-default.xml.template` and  `hivemetastore-site.xml`.

*More about the conf files:*

1. `hive-default.xml.template` contains the default values for various configuration variables that come prepackaged in a Hive distribution.
2. In order to override any of the values, create `hive-site.xml` instead and set the value in that file as shown above.
3. You can set metastore-specific configuration values in `hivemetastore-site.xml`.

**BTW:** `Derby` is the `default database` for the Hive metastore (Metadata Store).

[If you want to read more, the official docs](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/AdminManual+Configuration#AdminManualConfiguration-hive-site.xmlandhive-default.xml.template)

Comment: I dont have any of the entry in my hive-site.xml, does it mean it is derby?

Answer (score 3):

I know I'm bit late to the party but, I came up with a much more easier and handy solution to get the details of you metastore.

Open up your Hive Cli and type in below command

```
hive> set javax.jdo.option.ConnectionURL;
```

It should show your hive metastore URL which is defined in hive-site.xml, it should look like this

```
javax.jdo.option.ConnectionURL=jdbc:mysql://<hostName>:<port>/<database>?createDatabaseIfNotExist=true
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

Update the below property in Hive and deploy the same and then continue the installation.
Go to Hive->Configuration and upate below property:
Hive Metastore Database Host=
where FQDN is host where Name Node resides.

Example:
Hive Metastore Database Host=cloudera1.xyz.com